# how to find program files on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lts

I am new to ubuntu and I used to use windows OS. after installing ubuntu i installed wine software on ubuntu so i can run the .exe files.

now I successfully installed the .exe file on ubuntu and as the installation wizard mentioned, the files were installed on c:program files

my question is , where and how can I find c:program files on ubuntu i cant find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the `.wine` folder in your home directory. The dot at the beginning means it's hidden by default, so you may need to choose "Show Hidden Files" in your file manager.

Your Windows program will be in a folder similar to `/home/elpharaoh/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/`

Comment: in the path you specified there is no .wine folder

Comment: Have you chosen to enable viewing hidden files and folders in your file manager? As I said in my answer, this may need to be enabled before you can view the `.wine` folder.

Comment: actuallz i do not how to do that

Comment: Try looking in the "view" or "view options" menus.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your file manager, there are often ways to enter a path and go straight to it. This function is usually located under "Go" in your file manager, with a label like "Go to..." or "Open directory". Open it and enter `~/.wine` and your Wine folder will be opened.